# default http threadpool size in embedded tomcat server spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have a spring boot application which is running on embedded tomcat server. I want to know the default tomcat http threadpool size and how to check them.

After checking on various portal i got to know that we can add 'server.tomcat.max-threads' in the applications.properties file and control it.

But i want to understand what is the default size and how to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the default value for each property [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html) for the latest Spring Boot version. In this case the property is `server.tomcat.threads.max` and the default value is Tomcat's default, which is 200.